# iPhone Static Library Code Signing Issue

Tags: iphone, code-signing, static-libraries

I have a static library (SL) that can be build with "Debug" as the active target but not with "Distribution". I have set "Don't code sign" in the "Edit Project Settings" window but still get an error saying that the SL cannot be code signed. Isn't that strange? I'm using Xcode 3.2.1. Has anyone had the same issue and knows how to resolve it?

CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Bundle' in SDK 'Device - iPhone OS 3.0'

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the code signing profile in the target and in the project.